# Javascript sort object by key within nested objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have the following object:

```
{
  4: {
    1: [
      { order: 1, name: 'Test 4' }
    ]
  },
  0: {
    15: [
      { order: 7, name: 'Test 1' },
      { order: 3, name: 'Test 3' },
    ],
    12: { 
      { order: 1, name: 'Test 2' }
    }
  }
}
```

Essentially what I am trying to achieve is to order this by the keys and then order further by the order property from within the nested value. So in turn I get the following output:

```
{
  0: {
    12: { 
      { order: 1, name: 'Test 2' }
    },
    15: [
      { order: 3, name: 'Test 3' },
      { order: 7, name: 'Test 1' },
    ]
  },
  4: {
    1: [
      { order: 1, name: 'Test 4' }
    ]
  }
}
```

I then want to completely flatten this so it's without any of the outer object and just the data within the order, the outcome would then be:

```
[
  { name: 'Test 2' },
  { name: 'Test 3' },
  { name: 'Test 1' },
  { name: 'Test 4' }
]
```

I imagine this would be some kind of recursive operation which I need to do and I originally did it with something like the following but it got a bit messy:

```
Object.keys(obj)
  .sort()
  .reduce((acc, key) => { acc[key] = obj[key]; return acc; }, {});
```

Comment: This is an object, though, so it doesn't *really* have an order?

Comment: Do you need the intermediary object as part of your output or is just the final array fine?

Comment: @NickParsons I think just the final array would be fine

Comment: @kelly I understand that but that's why I want to manipulatethe property in order to achieve the ordering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anotner one sorting approach

```js
const obj = {4:{1:[{order:1,name:'Test 4'}]},0:{15:[{order:7,name:'Test 1'},{order:3,name:'Test 3'},],12:[{order:1,name:'Test 2'}]}};

const result = Object.entries(obj).flatMap(([u1, v1]) => 
    Object.entries(v1).flatMap(([u2, v2]) => 
        v2.map((v3) => ({ key: u1*1_000 + u2 + v3.order/1_000, item: v3 }))
    )
)
.sort(({ key: a }, { key: b }) => a - b)
.map(({ item }) => item);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort each obj by keys using `Object.keys(obj).sort()` and then access each element by its key.

Do this 2 times to get the array of object

```js
const obj = {
  4: {
    1: [
      { order: 1, name: 'Test 4' }
    ]
  },
  0: {
    15: [
      { order: 7, name: 'Test 1' },
      { order: 3, name: 'Test 3' },
    ],
    12: [ 
      { order: 1, name: 'Test 2' }
    ]
  }
}

let flatItems = []
const keys = Object.keys(obj).sort()

for (const key of keys){
  const subObj = obj[key]
  
  const subKeys = Object.keys(subObj).sort()
  
  for(const subKey of subKeys){
   flatItems = flatItems.concat(subObj[subKey].sort((a, b) => a.order - b.order))
  }
}

console.log(flatItems)
```

Answer (score 0):

Object keys can’t easily be sorted, the iteration order depends on different rules and isn’t straightforward to work with. As a result you’re better off converting your object into an array of key-value pair arrays (entries), and then sort that array rather than trying to sort your object (sorting is required as your object can have non-array index keys such as -1).

To do this, you can create a recursive function (`sortEntries`) that takes your object and grabs the [entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) from it. Using the key component of the entries, you can [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) based on that. Once you've sorted the entries, you can [`.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) the result of recursively sorting your nested object value by calling the `sortEntries` function again. For the base case (termination case), you can stop the recursion once you've found a value that is an array, which for that you can sort by the `order` property for your objects and then [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) each object to extract only the `name` property. Each array returned by `.map()` will be merged together into one resulting array due to the previous `.flatMap()` call:

```js
const obj = { 4: { 1: [ { order: 1, name: 'Test 4' } ] }, 0: { 15: [ { order: 7, name: 'Test 1' }, { order: 3, name: 'Test 3' }, ], 12: [ { order: 1, name: 'Test 2' } ] } };

const sortEntries = (obj) => {
  return Array.isArray(obj)
    ? obj.slice().sort((a, b) => a.order - b.order).map(({name}) => ({name}))
    : Object.entries(obj).sort(([a], [b]) => a - b).flatMap(([, val]) => sortEntries(val));
}

const res = sortEntries(obj);
  
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

The integer properties (in the range of 32 bit unsigned integers) don't need sorting, as iteration over them (e.g. via `Object.values`) is **by specification** already sorted by those integer keys. So the logic needs to focus only on sorting the inner objects, and it will be fine.

```js
const flatSort = obj => Array.isArray(obj)
    ? [...obj].sort((a, b) => a.order - b.order).map(a => a.name)
    : Object.values(obj).flatMap(flatSort);

const obj = { 4: { 1: [ { order: 1, name: 'Test 4' } ] }, 0: { 15: [ { order: 7, name: 'Test 1' }, { order: 3, name: 'Test 3' }, ], 12: [ { order: 1, name: 'Test 2' } ] } };
const res = flatSort(obj);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Full Key/Value object sorting (array values included):

```js
function sortKeys(object) {
  if (Array.isArray(object))
    return object.sort().map((obj) => (typeof obj === "object" ? sortKeys(obj) : obj));

  const sortedObj = {};
  const keys = Object.keys(object).sort();

  for (var index in keys) {
    const key = keys[index];
    if (typeof object[key] === "object") {
      sortedObj[key] = sortKeys(object[key]);
    } else {
      sortedObj[key] = object[key];
    }
  }

  return sortedObj;
}
```